# Conditional text in woocommerce email-footer template based on product categories that were purchased in order

Tags: woocommerce, conditional-statements, email-templates

I have looked at a few conditions that I have found on stackexchange and woocommerce dev docs. However, I am having a tough time with integrating it.

I am trying to add certain text to the FOOTER template in the email that woocommerce sends outs. We are wanting to only condition an array of product categories that are set that show this conditional text.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Product Categories that it should be shown: 25, 28, 433

+++++ email-footer.php ++++++

```
if ( condition here ) {

<p>Here is the conditional text I want to show if the product from the order is in these categories '25, 28, 433'</p>


}
```